# Unsure why I'm getting an injection error using ui.router

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router

I have some code and at this point, I'm just trying to follow the 'Getting started' section of the UI Router page to get something going on my current application.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('configurator.boot', ['configurator.errorhandler', 'configurator.routes', 'ui.router']);

    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        console.log($stateProvider);
    });

    app.run(function () { });
})();
```

I get this error when loading my page:

```
Failed to instantiate module configurator.boot due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=a
    at Error (native)
    at http://wkslt-139998:96/configurator/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:6:450
    at http://wkslt-139998:96/configurator/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:36:202
    at c (http://wkslt-139998:96/configurator/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://wkslt-139998:96/configurator/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:35:6)
    at http://wkslt-139998:96/configurator/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:33:394
    at r (http://wkslt-139998:96/configurator/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:7:290)
    at e (http://wkslt-139998:96/configurator/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:33:207)
    at ec (http://wkslt-139998:96/configurator/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:36:309)
    at c (http://wkslt-139998:96/configurator/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:18:170
```

If I just log 'hello', that works, so that leads me to think that I need to add some other dependency to the module function, but I don't know what.

Thank you for any help you can give me, I've been grinding my wheels for a day with just getting started.

Comment: also, use `$log` service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the minification process.  Changing it to:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('configurator.boot', ['configurator.errorhandler', 'configurator.routes', 'ui.router'])
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            console.log($stateProvider);
    }]);

    app.run(function () { });
})();
```

fixed it up.